# How test redirect in Cypress implemented with window.open

Tags: cypress

How to test the redirection implemented with **window.open**?

What am i doing wrong?
I want to intercept redirection implemented by window.open().

```
  it("Form is opened", () => {
    cy.visit(`http://localhost:28080/app/form`, {
      onBeforeLoad(win) {
        cy.stub(win, 'open').as('windowOpen');
      }
    });
  });
```

```
... 
  describe("Field test", () => {

      redirectButton().click();
      cy.get('@windowOpen').then($w => {
        debugger;
      })
    });
```

But onClick on RedirectButton Cypress redirects to no-test page that says *Whoops, there is no test to run.*

[image]

But if I change my redirectButton implementation from window.open to location.href it redirects to the correct page and finishes this test successfully.

I tried on Cypress 3.8 and 4.9